# Sql compare almost equal records

Tags: mysql, sql, match-against

I have such records in db:

```
Тормозной диск
```

and

```
Диски тормозные LPR
```

etc

and i try to compare

```
Тормозной диск
```

with

```
Диски тормозные LPR
```

here

```
select * from (....) where match(`cross_value`) against ("*Тормозной диск*" in boolean mode)
```

Sure it give me that it doesn't include it...

But how can i tell mysql, that it is true? That `Диски Тормозные` and `Тормозной Диск` is the same and inclusion => true?

Comment: How close do they have to be in concrete terms for it to be a match? Do you want to check for edit distance?

Comment: @Asad  m? didn't understand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, include your terms as mandatory:

```
select * from (....)
where match(`cross_value`) against ('+Тормозн* +диск*' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: but note... that it is not one case... there are many situationsm so ** is good here... it could be in sentence, in start or end, etc...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 If these are whole words, they will be found, no matter where in the sentence they are. If they are part of a word, add an asterisk.

Comment: Yes, but have you tested it *without* asterisk and with plus?

Comment: Judging from your example records, I have adjusted my answer. Please, try again.

Comment: tested... is bad idea... And '+Тормозн* +диск*' is the worst idea, becouse it all is dynamic, i will not shrink words, put where need asterix, where +... it must be universal thing

Comment: Also, how to do it non-case-sensetive? And i could search via ормоз иск but i need two words included in search (+) and *ормоз* *иск* so it could be before and after something, but two words are in need

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18803/discussion-between-olaf-dietsche-and-brabertaser1992)